# Is desktop restore expected to override --no-window-system?

Tags: osx, frames, desktop

When I run `emacs -nw` (`--no-window-system`) emacs (v29.1 on macOS v13.6.1) initially begins running in the terminal window, with the terminal clearing and the modeline appearing at the bottom.  Quite quickly, however, `desktop-load-file` begins and after a few seconds the terminal window reverts to showing the previous command line output and multiple frames (i.e. separate macOS windows) open containing my previously-visited buffers.

After desktop restoration completes, `window-system` is set to `ns`, even though it is normally `nil` when running `-nw`.

Is it expected that desktop restoration be able to override the `-nw` command line argument in this way?

I do not recall seeing this behaviour previously, but possibly because usually when I run `emacs -nw` I still have my main emacs process running so `desktop` prompts me whether I wish to restore the desktop and I decline.

---

Here's everything in my `init.el` that concern windowing system / desktop:

```
(when window-system
  (setq confirm-kill-emacs 'yes-or-no-p))
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (when (require 'exec-path-from-shell nil 'noerror)
    (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)))
(when window-system
  (if (fboundp 'gnuserv-start)
      (gnuserv-start))
  (server-start))
(require 'desktop)  ; Seems unnecessary - deleting has no effect.

(custom-set-variables
 '(desktop-restore-in-current-display nil)
 '(desktop-restore-reuses-frames nil)
 '(desktop-save-mode t)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(initial-frame-alist '((width . 132) (height . 50) (top . 100) (left . 300)))
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
```

I was able to prevent this undesirable (to me) behaviour by removing `desktop-save-mode` from `custom-set-variables` and instead adding

```
(when window-system (desktop-save-mode t))
```

further up my `init.el` file.

Answer (score 2):

`-nw` means "create the initial frame as a terminal frame", not "create *only* terminal frames". The resulting Emacs can still create graphical frames, as you've seen. If you don't want  `desktop` restoring frames, you can set `desktop-restore-frames` to `nil`

Comment: Section C.2 (Initial Options) of the emacs manual says "‘--no-window-system’: Don’t communicate directly with the window system, disregarding the ‘DISPLAY’ environment variable even if it is set. This means that Emacs uses the terminal from which it was launched for all its display and input."

Moreover, when I start emacs from the command line with `-nw` I am unable to create additional frames via `C-x 5 2`, and evaling `(make-frame)` returns (e.g.) `#<frame F2 0x139acd980>` but does not create any new macOS windows.

Comment: @cpcallen Try `M-x make-frame-on-display`